# File uploading using AJAX is not working in Django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, jquery-upload-file-plugin

I'm trying to upload file using onchange event and AJAX but it is not working. I'm getting file path on backend not actual file.
I want to modify this code such that when pdf file selected the file automatically get uploaded and can be use in views.py.

a.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title> Django image and file upload using ajax </title>
  </head>
<body>
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="id_ajax_upload_form" method="POST" novalidate="">
     {%csrf_token%}
      <input type="file" id="resumes" onchange="funct()" name="resumes">
       <span>File</span>
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file" size="10"/>
      <input id="uploadbutton" type="button" value="Upload"/>
   </form>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function getCookie(name) {
       var cookieValue = null;
       if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
           var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
           for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
               var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
               // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
               if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                   cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
       return cookieValue;
   }
   var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
   function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
       // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
       return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
   }
   $.ajaxSetup({
       beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
           if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
               xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
           }
       }
   });
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#file").change(function(){
       var filename = $("#file").val();
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "",
           enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
           data: {
               file: filename,
           },
           success: function () {
               // alert("Data Uploaded: ");
           }
       });
     })
   })

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Views.py:

```
def django_image_and_file_upload_ajax(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("working..............")
        print(request.POST.get('file'))
        print(request.FILES.get('file'))
        print(request.FILES.getlist("file"))
        print("...................................................")
        print(request.POST.get('data'))
        print(request.FILES.get('data'))
        print(request.FILES.getlist("data"))
        return JsonResponse({'error': False, 'message': 'file'})
    return render(request, 'a.html')
```

Console output on selecting a file:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 08, 2020 - 06:55:41
Django version 3.1.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Not Found: /
[08/Dec/2020 06:55:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2131
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[08/Dec/2020 06:55:46] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2182
[08/Dec/2020 06:55:51] "GET /URL1/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2318
working..............
C:\fakepath\dummy3.pdf
None
[]
...................................................
None
None
[]
[08/Dec/2020 06:56:09] "POST /URL1/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 200 35
```

How can I get file on backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post the files as `form data` as below :

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
   url : 'your_url',
   type : 'POST',
   data : formData,
   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   success : function(data) {
       # success
   }
});
```